# User Can Open Case of Record Type and Open Report of Case Record Type - No cases in Report

Tags: reporting, case, permissions

I have a profile that is assigned to see cases of a particular record type and they can view those cases.

We have a report that displays cases with the filter criteria being cases of that record type.

The user can open the report, but no cases are populated into the report. Where as logging into another user can see records in the case report. I can't identify the difference.

What am I missing?

WHAT I HAVE CONFIRMED:

- Profile can search and open case if provided case number. (Case Number received from report that populates records for me)
- Profile has Read and View All permission for Cases.
- Profile is assigned    "Record Type A" of cases.
- Report Show setting is set to "All Cases"
- Report Filter Criteria is set to Case Record Type = "Record Type A"
- Sharing Rules confirms View All permission activated for this
  profile.
- Profile can open report, but report is not populated with    any
  records.

Comment: Do you have a filter criteria set on your report?

Comment: @JayantDas the filter criteria is filtering case for the record type that the user has access to.

Comment: Then you should look at the sharing settings here, with details around as provided in the answer by sfdcfox.

Comment: At this point, either the report has a buggy filter, or there's a bug in the system. Try contacting support.

Comment: Can you provide some more details here - 1. What is the object type being referred? 2. Are both users (impacted vs. non impacted) have a role assigned to them? 3. Providing a screenshot of the report and its criteria will be helfpul. I hope you have already gone through this [**Knowledge article**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005085&type=1) as part of troubleshooting.

Comment: I appreciated the knowledge Article Jayant, I had not found this. 

It eventually led to my resolution. Specifically the FAQ: Have fields from a Child object been selected to be displayed, filtered upon or summed?
If a field is incorporated from a report within a standard report type it may change the dynamic of the report. It was displaying a contact object, which they had access to some record types for the contact object, but not all of the record types which were displaying in the report. If you would like to respond to this question as an answer I will mark it as correct.